# How to loop through a column name for for all the rows in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

Im trying to print only the 17th element of all the  rows. my code is something like this

```
csvFile = open('Workbook1.csv')
fileread = csv.reader(csvFile)
dataRead = list(fileread)
x=1
for items in dataRead[x][17]:
    x += dataRead.__len__()
    print items
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('Workbook1.csv', 'rt') as finput:
    for row in csv.reader(finput):
        print(row[16])
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your CSV is always properly formatted (ie. the number of columns is consistent) you can simply do this :

```
csvFile = open('Workbook1.csv')
fileread = csv.reader(csvFile)
for rows in fileread:
    print rows[16] # assuming you DID mean 17th item, then the array starts from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
i=0
while i <len(dataRead):
    i += 1
    print dataRead[i][0],dataRead[i][17]
```

Now it gives me first  element of row 1 along with the 16th element of row 1 and loops in through  all the rows. Is this a safe priactise to code? Sorry im  new to python..

Comment: I think i found answer myself. Anyways thank you guys :)

Comment: That'll get the 18th element, not the 17th element.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
for items in dataRead[x][17]:
    x += dataRead.__len__()
    print items
```

loops through the items in the 18th column of only the second row. You want to loop through every row, and access the 17th column in each:

```
for items in dataRead:
    print items[16]
```

Remember that Python is zero-indexed, so you need `16` instead of `17`. Also, when you need the length of an item, use `len(item)` rather than `item.__len__()`.

Comment: Sorry by 17th element i mean the 16 as it starts with index 0. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If someone would tell me what's wrong with this answer to the point that it deserves a downvote, I would love to know so that I can improve it.